# Polymer iron-dropdown with a paper-icon-button trigger

Tags: angular, polymer-2.x

I have an Angular site with Polymer and I want to have a notifications section on my header, but I can't make the button work.
How should I bind the click event on the button to trigger the dropdown?

This is the code I have:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="mail" slot="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
<paper-badge label="9" class="notification-badge"></paper-badge>
<iron-dropdown>
  <ul slot="dropdown-content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</iron-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `open()` method on your `iron-dropdown` as in the code below and [this Codepen.io example](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/rGRLpN?editors=1000):

```
<dom-module id="x-select">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-icon-button icon="mail" alt="mail" slot="dropdown-trigger" on-tap="open"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-badge label="9"></paper-badge>
    <iron-dropdown id="dropdown">
      <ul slot="dropdown-content">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </iron-dropdown>
  </template>
  <script>
    class XSelect extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'x-select'; }
      open() {
        this.$.dropdown.open();
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(XSelect.is, XSelect);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<x-select></x-select>
```